# Dynamically block IP address to azure cloud service

Tags: asp.net, azure, ip, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure cloud service (classic) that is our web app.  How can we tell the service to block specific IP's on all instances?

I know we can block using IIS 8+ Dynamic IP Restrictions (DIPR), when set through the web.config file.  [Configuring Dynamic IP Restrictions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/)

2 problems with this is that 1) We cannot add to the always block list from within the app and 2) Even if I could get that working, it would only be on that instance.

Is there no way to block/IP Filter traffic from the portal?
And can it be set from within our Cloud Service?

Comment: Any processnow?

Comment: Still no progress on that.  I ended up implementing Azure Application Gateway Firewall. (WAF)  Still working out the kinks in it though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there no way to block/IP Filter traffic from the portal? And can it be set from within our Cloud Service?

Each time your instance starts it will look at the endpoints which have been configured for the Role and open the required ports in the Firewall. What we'll do in our code is simply **disable these rules and create new rules which are restricted to a few IP addresses / IP address ranges**.

The core of this solution is the `IPAddressRestrictionManager.cs` class, that parses settings from the `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` (which you can modify while the application is deployed) and modifies the Firewall on each instance.

First you need to install the NuGet package:

```
PM> Install-Package WindowsAzure.IPAddressRestriction
```

If you want to link the `IPAddressRestrictionManager` to your `ServiceConfiguration` you'll need to add the following settings to your Role:

[image]

The syntax for the settings isn't too hard to understand:

`IPAddressRestriction.Enabled = true` or `false`

`IPAddressRestriction.Settings` = = or =- (delimiter between ports is ";")

Finally you need to hook everything up in your WebRole/WorkerRoler.cs

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint  
{
    private IPAddressRestrictionManager restrictionManager;

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        RoleEnvironment.Changing += OnRoleEnvironmentChanging;
        ConfigureIPAddressRestrictions();
        return base.OnStart();
    }

    private void ConfigureIPAddressRestrictions()
    {
        if (restrictionManager == null)
            restrictionManager = new IPAddressRestrictionManager();

        restrictionManager.RemoveRestrictions();
        if (restrictionManager.IsEnabledInConfiguration())
            restrictionManager.ApplyFromConfiguration();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Force restart of the instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void OnRoleEnvironmentChanging(object sender, RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Changes.Any(o => o is RoleEnvironmentChange))
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](http://fabriccontroller.net/apply-ip-address-restrictions-to-your-windows-azure-cloud-services/).

Comment: Thanks Joey! This is close, but not quite there.  I need to allow all IP's by default, then block them from code as needed.  This seems to be hard-coded to block everything and allow only certain IP's.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I've also spent the day reading about ACL and also trying to get PowerShell scripts to run.  Unfortunately, there seems to be no API/interface to ACL and there seems to be no way to execute a PS script as administrator, so I am back to square 1.

Comment: I dug into the code from the article you suggested which eventually led me to this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/501194/Allow-Block-a-Program.  However, I get Access Denied when running under my web context.

Comment: You could try to fix your problem by this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/894433/you-may-receive-an-access-is-denied-error-message-when-you-try-to-debu).